# Strategy to sign in users via facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, oauth, architecture, facebook-login

This is my strategy that I've implemented in my web app.
The client( js app ) gets the access_token from facebook and using the access token, I fetch the details of the user like email, user_id etc. I save the details in my database. This ends the signup part.

During sign in, the client sends the access_token and the server fetchs the user_details from facebook using the access_token. Then I find the user by fb_user_id and create a session for him.

How can I ensure that the access_token that the server got during the sign in process is sent by my app and not any other app that has access_token of one of my user ?

Comment: why would any other app has access tokens of your users? you should keep them safe, of course ;)

Comment: my user might have logged into another app via facebook and if he uses that access token with my api, I would be making a request to fb using it, fetch his fb_user_id and create a session for him.

Comment: you do know that he will have a different id in that other app, right? i am not sure what you are asking here, to be honest. another app usually means another url, another login, and so on...